# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am currently working on CodeIgniter charts, but am getting an error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

And charts are not loading showing blank.

```
var data_course_stats = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Course', 'Time spent',{ role: 'style' }],
           <?php 
           $i=0;
           foreach ($timespent_stats as $course) { $course = (object)$course;
           $color_val = 'green';
            if(count($i<count($timespent_stats)))
              $color_val = $colors[$i++];
            ?>
         ['<?php echo $course->title;?>', <?php echo $course->spent_seconds/60;?>,'<?php echo $color_val; ?>'],
         <?php } ?>
        ]);

        var options_course_stats = {
          title: 'Course Wise Spent Time in Minutes',
          curveType: 'function',
           height: 400,
             bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
          legend: { position: "none" },
};
```

Comment: The code appears to be incomplete - Is there surrounding HTML? Also does the dev console report which line has the error?

Comment: Why does some of your PHP have quotation marks around it and not others? Are you trying to **echo** the PHP into the JavaScript, or are you trying to have a **string** containing the PHP code? Either way, that's inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you have accepted the answer, i want to add the another technique which is little simpler than the previous one. You can perform echo with `<?=` like `<?php echo something; ?>` so you can simply do this `<?= something ?>`

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($timespent_stats as $course) { 
    $course = (object)$course;
    $color_val = 'green';

    if(count($i<count($timespent_stats)))
        {
        $color_val = $colors[$i++];
?>
        [<?= $course->title ?>, <?= $course->spent_seconds/60 ?>, <?= $color_val ?>]
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For longer blocks, to keep PHP open - you're getting in trouble because you're mixing and matching open and closed.  Change this:

```
       <?php 
       $i=0;
       foreach ($timespent_stats as $course) { $course = (object)$course;
       $color_val = 'green';
        if(count($i<count($timespent_stats)))
          $color_val = $colors[$i++];
        ?>
     ['<?php echo $course->title;?>', <?php echo $course->spent_seconds/60;?>,'<?php echo $color_val; ?>'],
     <?php } ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php 
       $i=0;
       foreach ($timespent_stats as $course) { 
         $course = (object)$course;
         $color_val = 'green';
         if(count($i<count($timespent_stats))) {
            $color_val = $colors[$i++];

            echo "['" . $course->title . "','" .  
                        $course->spent_seconds/60 . "','" . 
                        $color_val . "']"; 
         }
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: i have another issue i  developed a plugin in codeigniter .it is working in localhost very well but when i upload it in server it displaying only half screen remaining not displaying when i click on inspect element showing error like internal server error 500

Comment: Sairam, you will need to open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get this problem again, check if your base_url is correct in config/config.php